# Did I setup my unifi router correctly as an openvpn client?

Tags: routes, client, openvpn

Looking to route traffic to a private subnet associated with my VPN through my router that is set up as a client.

When I run a trace route to the subnet (10.202.xxx.xxx) the first hop goes to my default GW of the router (192.168.xxx.xxx) then out to my ISP instead of to the VPN client interface. So from my view point it doesn't look like the traffic is being routed properly.

I have a ubiquiti dream router that has the option of attaching an openvpn client file to it to allow communication with my openvpn server. I've added the file and show a connection between the router and VPN. I've added a route within the router that if it sees traffic from any device regarding the private subnet (10.202.xxx.xxx) it should go through the client interface.

- I've tried changing it from just the subnet traffic to all internet traffic with the same results.
- I've also limited it to on device instead of all devices on the network, also with the same results.
- I've tried setting up the client as a "VPN gateway" within the server settings targeting the subnet of the router (192.168.xxx.xxx), with the same results as the previous attempts.
  -lastly I tried setting it up as a static router instead of a generic route on the router with the same results.

With all of these attempts I've done a trace route to the subnet and captured traffic from on the openvpn server with no luck on the server side.

Overall it seems like the router is not observing the routes that I've setup within it and not sure what to do further from here. Would appreciate any assistance.